# FFMPEG muxed as a private data stream and may not be recognized upon reading

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, m3u8, mkv

I've came across a mkv with a codec of hevc , while trying to either convert it to m3u8 or mp4 I received this following message:

[mpegts @ 0x7f94de014600] Stream 1, codec flac, is muxed as a private data stream and may not be recognized upon reading.

Is there something wrong with my ffmpeg parameters?

To m3u8:
#1 :

```
ffmpeg -i aaa.mkv -s 1920x1080 -codec copy -bsf:v hevc_mp4toannexb -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -segment_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls aaa.m3u8
```

#2 :

```
ffmpeg -i aaa.mkv -s 1920x1080 -codec copy -c:v libx264 -bsf:v hevc_mp4toannexb -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -segment_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls aaa.m3u8
```

To mp4:

#1 :

```
ffmpeg -i aaa.mkv -c copy ccc.mp4
```

#2 :

```
ffmpeg -y -i aaa.mkv -codec copy -strict -2 ccc.mp4
```

Edit:
FFMPEG dump:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'aaa.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.4 + libmatroska v1.4.5
    creation_time   : 2016-12-20T17:13:09.000000Z
  Duration: 00:24:18.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4395 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 96.096000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER00
    Chapter #0:1: start 96.096000, end 134.050000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER01
    Chapter #0:2: start 134.050000, end 224.099000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER02
    Chapter #0:3: start 224.099000, end 708.082000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER03
    Chapter #0:4: start 708.082000, end 1302.050000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER04
    Chapter #0:5: start 1302.050000, end 1392.015000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER05
    Chapter #0:6: start 1392.015000, end 1428.051000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER06
    Chapter #0:7: start 1428.051000, end 1458.920000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER07
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 3671317
      BPS-eng         : 3671317
      DURATION        : 00:24:18.916000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:24:18.916000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 34979
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 34979
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 669518018
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 669518018
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.4.2 ('So High') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.4.2 ('So High') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-12-20 17:13:09
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-12-20 17:13:09
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 722497
      BPS-eng         : 722497
      DURATION        : 00:24:18.920000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:24:18.920000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 17097
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 17097
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 131758259
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 131758259
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.4.2 ('So High') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.4.2 ('So High') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-12-20 17:13:09
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-12-20 17:13:09
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Output #0, hls, to 'aaa.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 96.096000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER00
    Chapter #0:1: start 96.096000, end 134.050000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER01
    Chapter #0:2: start 134.050000, end 224.099000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER02
    Chapter #0:3: start 224.099000, end 708.082000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER03
    Chapter #0:4: start 708.082000, end 1302.050000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER04
    Chapter #0:5: start 1302.050000, end 1392.015000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER05
    Chapter #0:6: start 1392.015000, end 1428.051000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER06
    Chapter #0:7: start 1428.051000, end 1458.920000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER07
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 3671317
      BPS-eng         : 3671317
      DURATION        : 00:24:18.916000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:24:18.916000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 34979
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 34979
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 669518018
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 669518018
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.4.2 ('So High') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.4.2 ('So High') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-12-20 17:13:09
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-12-20 17:13:09
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 722497
      BPS-eng         : 722497
      DURATION        : 00:24:18.920000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:24:18.920000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 17097
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 17097
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 131758259
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 131758259
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.4.2 ('So High') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.4.2 ('So High') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-12-20 17:13:09
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-12-20 17:13:09
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpegts @ 0x7f8b8a020e00] Stream 1, codec flac, is muxed as a private data stream and may not be recognized upon reading.
```

Comment: MPEG-TS does not support FLAC audio, but MP4 should be fine.

Comment: @Gyan hi, is there a way round from MKV to M3U8/TS? I've tried ways like first converting to MP4 then to convert it to M3U8/TS , but it still doesn't seem to work

Tried this command but still getting the same codec flac error:
ffmpeg -i aaa.mkv -s 1920x1080 -codec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -c:v libx264 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -segment_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls ccc.mp4

Comment: Change `-codec copy` to `-c:v copy` in your original command.

Comment: @Gyan Tried ffmpeg -i aaa.mkv -c:v copy -strict -2 ccc.mp4 works, but the MP4 file is off , there's only audio